# Nginx-Ingress pod not schedulable

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm facing an issue of pod not scheduling for an ingress enabled application. The endpoints are ready but the pod is not schedulable. It would be great if anybody helps me with the solution.
[image]

Comment: output of kubectl get events

Comment: You would have to share the pod info